# Mysql does not store blob column data

Tags: php, mysql, oop, blob

I have strange problem that I am unable to figure out, any help would be appreciated!.

The problem is I am trying to store an object into mysql database, when I execute the insertion command I run successfully, but when I check the table, all columns have the new inserted data expect the column with Blob datatype.

here is the table

```
CREATE TABLE `uc_opportunities` (
 `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `org_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `dateTime` int(11) NOT NULL,
`subject` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
`text` varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
`zipcode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`location` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`schedule` blob NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=48 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and here is the insertion function:

```
public function addOpportunity($org_id)
{
    global $mysqli,$emailActivation,$websiteUrl,$db_table_prefix; // 

    echo "inside add opportunity<br>";
    var_dump($this->schedule);

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO ".$db_table_prefix."opportunities (
        org_id,
        dateTime,
        subject,
        text,
        zipcode,
        schedule
        )
        VALUES (
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?,
        ?
        )");

    $schedule_serialized = serialize($this->schedule);      
    $stmt->bind_param("iissib", $org_id, $this->dateTime, $this->subject,$this->postText, $this->zipcode, $schedule_serialized );
    $result = $stmt->execute();

    echo "execution result ".$result."<br>";
    $inserted_id = $mysqli->insert_id;
    $stmt->close();

    $this->post_id = $inserted_id;

    }
```

All columns except **schedule** are inserted, I check if the insertion function receive the schedule correctly using var_dump($this->schedule) and it is correct. What do you think might be the problem?

Thank you

Comment: How are you checking the table?

Comment: You are not really using the blob column correctly. Blob is for Binary Large OBject data and is usually used for stuff like images. A serialize of an array/object is not binary data. It is text representing an array/object. You would likely want to use a `text` type column. I don't know what is in the schedule array/object/column, but I would also bet that you are not really "doing it right" because it should probably bet split into it's own table to allow for indexing and easier add/edit.

Comment: Check this out. It details how to use LOB data with mysqli. https://blogs.oracle.com/oswald/entry/php_s_mysqli_extension_storing. You essentially have to bind a null value and then use `send_long_data` to send the data in. As a note, the `text` type column doesn't need this extra step.

Comment: Thank you @JonathanKuhn, I change the datatype to text and it indeed did work. I used the wrong datatype which made me confused of why it was not store in the table. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the mysqli documentation in reference to saving blob data and mysql config for max_allowed_packet. It's possible this could be your issue since I don't know how big your serialized data is:

[php.net mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.send-long-data.php)

Answer (score 0):

first of all,change your data if it is image,audio,document etc into binary and  schedule column to longBlob then run your insert command.Some times due to larger binary data insert doesn`t work.So give a try